# Have I found all functional dependencies?

Tags: database, database-design

Working through an old textbook to get a better grasp on database concepts and I'm not sure if I have the below correct. Can anyone confirm or explain what I might be doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: "Only one employee represents a project" sounds like it is meant as a functional dependency. If we know the project, we know the employee. If we interpret that line to mean that only one employee represents a project *on a particular day, but the representative can be different the next day* then there is not much of a question left. So, given that it is an academic question, make that assumption, and proceed.

Comment: So then am I correct with what I have placed under A & B? or not?

Comment: In A, you are showing the multivalued dependency, but the question wants you to identiy the Functional dependency

Comment: True, but I'm not seeing any...?

Comment: Isn't the Multivalued Dependency I have listed the only dependency present given the situation?

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic: No, and multivalued dependencies aren't the same thing as functional dependencies. Meditate on ProjectName -> EmployeeName, and on ProjectName -> Date.

Comment: The question here is: are we talking about a meeting where people from different projects meet together on a date ; or people from the same project meet on a date?

Answer (score 2):

I find this ambigous and misleading, the supplied data does not help; seems that most people in the example like to meet themself.

> 1. Employee from a particular Project attended a meeting on a given Date.
> 2. Project meets at most once per day.
> 3. Only one Employee represents a given project, but that Employee can be assigned to multiple Projects.

- Q1: Is this a meeting for one project only, or meeting of people from different projects?
- Q2: What is Project? Does it mean that there can be series of project meetings on a given day, or just one meeting for all the projects on the day? Take for an example, `(Tim, FQLIMS, '8/4/2013') , (Tim, MSFCCS, '8/4/2013')`; was Tim in one meeting representing two projects, or was he in two projects meetings on that date?
- Q3: What is assigned? Is representing a project the same as being assigned to it? Is there one person per Project, or one project leader and more people assigned to it?

So, there is more than one way to interpret `{Employee, Project, Date}`, here are two version that I see:

1. Project was represented by Employee at staff meeting on Date.
2. Employee attended Project meeting on Date.

Obviously the data set in not sufficient,  each project is listed only once, while constraint allows for a meeting once per day. It is not possible to state functional dependencies from such data set, so semantics of constraints has to be used, and in this example it is ambiguous.

I will go with version 1 only because the small data-set supports it.

---

**Version 1**

Project was represented by Employee at staff meeting on a Date.

1.0 Project is represented by Employee.

Each Project is represented by exactly one Employee.
It is possible that more than one project is represented by the same Employee.

This obviously implies `FD  {Project} -> {Employee}`

1.1 Project was represented at staff meeting on a Date.

Each Project was represented at most once at staff meeting on a given date Date .

This leads to

```
PrjEmp {Project, Employee}  -- Project is represented by Employee
   KEY {Project} 

Meeting {Project, Date}      -- Project was represented at staff meeting on Date.
    KEY {Project, Date}
```